# Take a String array and split with ","

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need help with splitting a String array at each `,` and make the result a new string array.

```
String [] studentName ={"Thui Bhu, 100, 90, 80, 100, 89, 99, 88"}
```

Convert to:

```
String []studentName2={"Thui Bhu", "100", "90", "80", "100" "89", "99", "88"}
```

Comment: `studentName[0].split(",");`

Comment: use StringTokenizer Class :)

Comment: do you need to insert the quotes?

Answer (score 2):

specify the index of the array element where the splitting going to be occur.

```
    String [] studentName ={"Thui Bhu, 100, 90, 80, 100, 89, 99, 88"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(studentName[0].split(",")));
```

Comment: Hi Avinash, I need to return an array, not a string. I think toString() returns a String.

Comment: `studentName[0].split(",")` returns an array. You can't print an array directly, so that i used `Arrays.toString`

Comment: this is what i did: studentName[i]=studentName[i].split(",") but i get the error message: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String"

Comment: try `studentName = studentName[0].split(",");`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression `,\\s*` to split on a comma and consume any (optional) white-space like

```
String[] studentNames = { "Thui Bhu, 100, 90, 80, 100, 89, 99, 88" };
for (String studentName : studentNames) {
    String[] arr = studentName.split(",\\s*");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer implementation would be something like that:

```
StringTokenizer str = StringTokenizer(yourString, ",");

while(str.hasMoreTokens())
{
   //whatever you want to do here
}
```

**Note:** It is a legacy class and its use is discouraged.

**Recommended way:** Using split method of string is the recommended way.
Following is the example:

```
String[] result = "this,is,a,test".split(",");
     for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
         System.out.println(result[x]);
```

**Output:**
this
is
a
test